# Text visible on backside

Tags: modeling

I wrote text on an object, but it is visible on the backside of the object i.e.
 Image:

[image]

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOLHR.jpg

Comment: Your question is too jumbled. Please make sure you wrote everything right.

Comment: This post doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

One face has only one uv map and texture on both side. You have to make tickness for your paper, so you have to add a cube instead of a plane, and make it really thin, then unwrap it, so the frontface and the backface won't be the same.